# how to stop the while true loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I meet a question about the while true loop in python. 
The code is below

```
def batched(iterator, batch_size):

    while True:
        data = np.zeros(batch_size)
        target = np.zeros(batch_size)
        for index in range(batch_size):
            data[index], target[index] = next(iterator)

        yield data, target

batches = batched(examples, params.batch_size)

for index, batch in enumerate(batches):
    .......
    .......
```

there is no break in the loop, and it will keep true forever , so how can this loop can stop.
ps. the code is the examples in the book TensorFlow for Machine Intelligence .

Comment: `batched` is an iterator. The `yield` pauses the loop until the next time the iterator is called. So if the iteration (the `for` loop) has a terminating condition, we're good!
Consider reading up on `iterators` in python, it should clear up some things.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this answer because the comments section seemed a little too constricting.

First of all, reading up about `Iterators` in python will clear up your confusion.

I'll try to explain anyways! :D

---

```
def batched(iterator, batch_size):

    while True:
        data = np.zeros(batch_size)
        target = np.zeros(batch_size)
        for index in range(batch_size):
            data[index], target[index] = next(iterator)

        yield data, target
```

`batched` is a generator/iterator function. The key here is `yield`. When the program flow hits `yield`, the function "returns" the values (`data, target` in our case). *But the catch is, **only** when the function is called the next time, the flow continues from where it had `yielded` the last time.* In our case, the next time the function is called, the loop starts atop.

Now, as you might be misguided by the `while True:` loop without a `break`ing condition, `batched` is not a blocking function call.

Also, do note that,

```
batches = batched(examples, params.batch_size)
```

is not a function call. You just get a pointer to the iterator when you execute the above line. The function runs only when it's iterated over!

For you, it's being done here:

```
for index, batch in enumerate(batches):
```

Here again, the `for` loop would *fall into the infinite loop* if the terminator condition is not handled within the loop. Meaning, the loop needs to be terminated manually with a `break` inside the `for` loop.

Comment:  You're welcome. You may accept an answer as suited!

Answer (score 1):

This is a Python generator, it's not like a normal function that you'd call once, wait until it's finished and get the return value. It's used to generate data on the go, and these results come from `yield` keyword. 
So every time the infinite loop hits the yield keyword, it returns the current data and target, then it goes on. The simplest use of a generator is in a for loop:

```
for data, target in batched(iterator, batch_size):
    # do Something
```

The while loop breaks, once this for loop breaks (not fetches any more data).

You'll find some examples here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators#line-60

I couldn't find any example where they use an infinite loop inside the generator, but the concept is simple: your function can produce an infinite amount of results (could Fibonacci numbers), and it's handing over the control to the for loop which breaks if necessary.